# Navigation Drawer неправильно отображает fragment на телефоне

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-navigation-drawer

*Добрый день, вечер или ночь!*
Я создаю приложение , используя Navigation Drawer в Android Studio, но для дебаггинга я использую свой телефон *(Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge)*, который имеет разрешение 1440x2550 и 5,5inch , поэтому для создания дизайна и отображения его в Android Studio я создал девайс Pixel XL , который ,кажется, идентичен по разрешению, что и мой телефон, однако, после запуска я заметил, что то, что я создал в Android Studio в своём фрагменте отображается вовсе не так (как Вы видите кнопки Button слева наложились одна на другую на картинке 2).
[image: Дизайн внутри Android Studio] [image: Дизайн на телефоне]
XML-код разметки:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.calculator.Calculator" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="338dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Your operation is going to be here"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Result"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="279dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button12"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button11"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button13" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Как я понимаю, это связано с тем, что фрагмент сжимается из-за топ меню, **но как тогда создавать дизайн, если что бы я не делал оно сожмётся так, как я себе не могу представить**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в неправильном подходе к разметке. Не стоит пытаться подобрать размер кнопок под экран с помощью указания конкретных dp. К тому же согласно гайдам по материал дизайну при указании размеров элементов стоит давать их кратными 8dp или 4dp: [Understanding layout](https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html#resources)

В случае приведенного примера более лучшим выбором будет создать контейнер для кнопок, а самим кнопкам указать ширину 0pd ("match constraint") и отрегулировать вид весами:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Button"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTop="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTop="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"/>
        ...
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Button"
        ...
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTop="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTop="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Таким образом кнопки по горизонтали сами подгонятся под ширину экрана сохранив пропорции. В любом случае для больших элементов которые сильно зависят от размера экрана лучше указывать относительные размеры а не абсолютные.